# What is the best hack to remove bubbles?

Tags: cleaning, home, clothing, winter

What is the best way to remove "woollen bubbles", that arise on woollen clothing after some time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even high-quality sweaters and warm clothes produce bubbles which makes them look old and worn out. This is usually due to washing and due to ageing. I would suggest you do not use any machines for this problem.

- **Use a razor**: This is used currently in laundry. Electric or battery operated razor is not required. A use and throw type known as a disposable razor would be sufficient. Take care while using otherwise, it may cut your woolen clothes.
- **Use a pumice stone**: Easily available hack for this in the market. Rub it on your woolen clothes and see the hack solving easily.
- **Use a sand paper**: The second easily available hack in shops. Rub it in a single direction and hack works.

Whenever you wash your woolen clothes, always remember to wash them in detergents or conditioners made especially for them and not the washing powder available for washing fabrics of cotton, silk or other varieties.
Also remember that *Proper and tender care can keep your woolen clothes new for years together.*

Comment: I would prefer using a used razor. It certainly helps